# emacs:open file through ssh failed

Tags: emacs, ssh

When trying to open a file through ssh in emacs, I got an error:

```
Couldn't find a POSIX `id' command
```

**QUESTION:** What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does your remote system has proper `id` command? You can verify what TRAMP is trying to do if you set

```
(setq tramp-verbose 10)
```

Then try to connect and monitor buffers `*tramp/...*` and `*debug tramp/...*`. If the remote path does not get set correctly by TRAMP, you can change it:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/path/to/id/command")
```

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me recently for the first time... after never having the issue before on the same cluster of servers. It ended up being that the server I was trying to connect to was out of disk space...and this error was just a side effect of that. So it's worth doing a `df -h` if this issue seems to come out of nowhere.